# Distributed job queue with task locality?

Tags: database, distributed

**Context**

At present i have one server, which knows some tasks need to be scheduled at recurring intervals. So one process pushes such tasks into a message queue on a timer; and then other processes work on completing the tasks. There's a maximum number of workers that's based on server load and similar factors.

Now i must geographically distribute this system. There would be nodes in multiple regions with no predetermined master node, for fault-tolerance reasons.

Somehow, tasks must still be scheduled at the same recurring intervals. The knowledge of what tasks should be scheduled, is also distributed to all the nodes. It's OK for any node to work on any task, but if possible, nodes should prefer to work on tasks that are tagged as "theirs" i.e. near their geographic location. The results of worker tasks enter a multi-master replication.

But i don't know if there's software available that meets these needs.

**Question**

Is there a distributed message queue software library supporting task locality, distributed task injection, and network partitioning / loss of peers?